# Get access to the request headers from Axum IntoResponse

Tags: rust, rust-axum, rust-tower

I have a custom `IntoResponse` type that needs to return different data to the client depending on the value of the `Accept` header in the request.  I would prefer, if possible, to have this be seamless (i.e. I don't have to pass the header value into the `IntoResponse` type's constructor).  I thought the most straightforward way to accomplish this would be to write a layer using Axum's middleware system that all functions returning that type are required to be wrapped with, not have the type implement `IntoResponse`, and instead perform the conversion inside the middleware so that it could access the request headers, but it seems that Axum's middleware system requires the service function to return an `IntoResponse`.  Could I whip something up with a `tower::Layer` that does the same thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, lets get it out of the way that there is not a built-in mechanism to support the `Accept` header impacting the response. See [this brief discussion](https://github.com/tokio-rs/axum/discussions/1640).

---

You've probably noticed the [`IntoResponse`](https://docs.rs/axum/latest/axum/response/trait.IntoResponse.html) trait that handlers must yield does not provide access to the original request:

```
pub trait IntoResponse {
    fn into_response(self) -> Response<UnsyncBoxBody<Bytes, Error>>;
}
```

So you'd have to get the header from either the handler itself or some middleware.

Even worse, it requires the body be a sequence of bytes (which makes sense but loses type information). So a middleware would have to decode data from the encoded response body to modify it for a different mime type. This could probably work if your data is really simple, but for a lot of cases this would probably be an annoying and unnecessary cost. This data flow also impacts how underlying `tower` services can affect the response, so the distinction doesn't help.

---

Fortunately, there is another way: you can provide any data to your middleware via an [`Extension`](https://docs.rs/axum/latest/axum/struct.Extension.html). Through `.extensions()`/`.extensions_mut()` on a response, you can store arbitrary data, so your `IntoResponse` implementation can store itself in an extension that a middeware could then pull out and re-format as necessary.

Here's a mockup of how that could work:

```
use axum::http::header::ACCEPT;
use axum::http::{Request, StatusCode};
use axum::middleware::{from_fn, Next};
use axum::response::{Html, IntoResponse, Json, Response};
use axum::{routing::get, Router};
use serde::Serialize;

#[derive(Serialize)]
struct MyData {
    data: String,
}

impl IntoResponse for MyData {
    fn into_response(self) -> Response {
        let mut response = StatusCode::NOT_IMPLEMENTED.into_response();
        response.extensions_mut().insert(self);
        response
    }
}

async fn get_accept_aware() -> MyData {
    MyData {
        data: "test".to_owned(),
    }
}

async fn my_data_applicator<B>(request: Request<B>, next: Next<B>) -> Response {
    let accept_header = request
        .headers()
        .get(&ACCEPT)
        .map(|value| value.as_ref().to_owned());

    let mut response = next.run(request).await;

    if let Some(my_data) = response.extensions_mut().remove::<MyData>() {
        match accept_header.as_deref() {
            Some(b"application/json") => return Json(my_data).into_response(),
            Some(b"html") => return Html(format!("<body>{}</body>", my_data.data)).into_response(),
            _ => { /* yield original 501 response */ }
        }
    }

    response
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let app = Router::new()
        .route("/", get(get_accept_aware))
        .layer(from_fn(my_data_applicator));

    axum::Server::bind(&"0.0.0.0:3000".parse().unwrap())
        .serve(app.into_make_service())
        .await
        .unwrap();
}
```